# Como fechar um UserControl e abrir outro através do Panel

Tags: c#, visual-studio, panel, usercontrol

Eu tenho o userControlVehicles dentro de um Panel, nesse UserControl tem um botão para cadastrar um novo veiculo, eu quero que quando clicar no botão o panel feche ou esconda o UControl atual e mostre o novo, eu consegui fazer mostrar o de cadastro, mas não consigo fazer o antigo sumir..

```
private void metroButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UserControlCadastroVehicle userControlCadastroVehicle = new UserControlCadastroVehicle();
        panel1.Controls.Add(userControlCadastroVehicle);
        panel1.Controls.Remove(this);
    }
```

Achei que o Remove(this) fecharia o UserControl que eu estava, mas não funcionou, o Hide() ele até some, mas ai some tudo, até o de cadastro que eu abri.
[image: Fica assim]

Fica assim quando eu clico em cadastrar

Answer (score 0):

```
panel1.Controls.Clear();
        UserControlCadastroVehicle userControlCadastroVehicle = new UserControlCadastroVehicle();
        panel1.Controls.Add(userControlCadastroVehicle);
```

Consegui, foi mal pela nubada kkkk, comecei mexer com forms agora, mas caso algm caia aqui procurando a resposta, ta aí